# :hover tag refuses to work on any of my projects in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

Im new to coding and am currently in a HS class. I have been trying extremely hard to get some :hover tags to work, using the knowledge I have gained from this class. The issue is that no matter what the form is, my hover tag will not work.

Here is my bare bones code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  
    <title></title>
      <style>
          
          two {
              display: none;
          }
          
          one {
              display: block;
          }
          
          one:hover two {
              display: block;
          }
          
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
 
      <one>Hello</one>
      
      <two>Hello</two>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Its a highly simplified version of my actual project, and in the past, this seems to have worked. It now refuses to work no matter what I change. What am I missing  in this, and what are my mistakes?

Comment: You code `one:hover two` will work only if your code is : `<one><two></two></one>`. So, you need ton use example provided by Luis with sibling selector.

Answer (score 2):

Use general sibling selector (~):

```
one:hover ~ two {
              display: block;
          }
```

**DEMO HERE**
https://jsfiddle.net/9ascyo7k/

Comment: In this case, the direct sibling selector (`+`) would also work

Answer (score 0):

I guess proper tags are missing. Try to refer the code given below

```
  h2{
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    color: red;
   }
  h2:hover{
    background-color: black;
  }


 <h2>any</h2>
```